# Latent growth curve model - can I talk about an effect over time if I only have my outcome at the last timepoint?

Tags: intercept, time-varying-covariate, growth-model

I have a latent growth curve model with two variables. X (exposure to media) was measured at 5 time points over several years. Y (misinformation proneness) was measured only at the last time point (Time 5); the reason is that this measure is new, but ideally it should have been measured at all times and treated as time-varying.

In my model, Y at Time 5 is regressed on the intercept and slope of X - essentially it is treated as time-invariant outcome, if that makes any sense. My question is, with such a model, can I talk about a directional effect of the intercept of X on the outcome Y over time, or is it the equivalent of cross-sectional correlation - since the model treats Y as time-invariant and not time-varying?

Any help, or pointing me to literature that would answer this question, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is clear temporal precedence with regard to the X intercept factor (this factor represents the X true scores at Time 1). So the regression on the intercept factor clearly represents an effect over time. Of course, since you have measured Y only at Time 5, you cannot control for prior Y (Y at Time 1, autoregressive effect) like you could in a design in which both X and Y are repeatedly measured. But the design is still "stronger" in terms of examining causal effects than a purely cross-sectional design.

With regard to the slope factor, in a linear growth model, there would also be temporal precedence of the slope since the rate of change is the same between all time points with linear growth. The interpretation of the effect of a non-linear growth factor may be more tricky.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed, my doubt had to do with the fact that the autoregressive effect is not in the model. Could I argue that, since X is measured at several occasions and these measurements are, in a way, controlled for (because the slope factor is part of the same regression), at least I have accounted for the autoregressive effect for X and the correlations of the later time points of X with Y? I am wondering if I am not going too far with trying to apply the CLPM logic to a growth curve.

Comment: Since Y is your outcome (not X), the concern would be more that you cannot control for prior Y (unless you have a proxy for Y that was measured at an earlier time point). I don't see how it would be necessary to argue that prior X was controlled for since X isn't an outcome variable in your study.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot!